Can’t access funds
I tried to send my crypto tokens from my phantom wallet to my Coinbase account on solana network, it instead got sent to solscan now I can’t access My funds,

could you please expand more on what happened cause solscan is an explorer and i'm not sure you can send tokens to an explorer. You get sent to the explorer(solscan) to view transaction details If you could send a screenshot of what you are shown on solscan would help identify where your funds may have been sent
